# Trying to understand the difference between two polymorphic commands in Java

Tags: java, methods, polymorphism, equals, tostring

I have these two classes:

```
public class A {
    private final static A five = new A(5);
    public final int x;
    public A(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return x == ((A) o).x;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return equals(five) ? "five" : (x + "");
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public final int x;
    public B(int x) {
        super(x);
        this.x = x + 1;
    }
    public boolean equals(A o) {
        return x == o.x;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "B: " + super.toString();
    }
}
```

These are the 2 lines in my `main` program:

```
System.out.println(new B(5));
System.out.println((new B(5)).equals(new A(5)));
```

I know that in Java the method called is decided by the Object type,
in both of the lines the Object is of type `B`, so in the first line i have a call to `B` class `toString()` method,
from there after it prints "B: " it calls `A` class `toString()`, and now it tries to activate the `equals()` method.
From my understanding on polymorphism in Java the Object type i still `B`, so it will try to activate `B`'s `equals()` method, but actually while debugging it activates the `A` class `equals()`, that's the first thing i don't understand.

Later in the 2nd line of my `main` program i'm initializing a `B` Object, and calling the `equals()` method, so after i've seen how the first line of code behaves i said well OK, i'll call the `A` `equals()` but in practice this line goes to `B`'s `equals`...

I'm a bit confused, first the 2 lines of my `main` program behaves differently from what i know about how polymorphic code works, and the 2 lines behave differently although they should act the same...

Hope you could enlighten me about how this code works and why.

Comment: `equals(A o)` doesn't override `equals(Object o)`.

Comment: @biziclop i thought about that, but than how the two lines call different `equals()` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equals() method in B doesn't override the equals() method in A. One takes an Object as argument, and the other takes an A as argument.

When A.toString() is compiled, the compiler looks for a method in A and all its superclasses named equals(), and taking an A of any of its superclasses/interfaces as argument. And the only one existing is A.equals(Object). So that's what toString() uses.

Polymorphism allows choosing the appropriate method at runtime based on the type of the object **on which** the method is called. Not on the types of the arguments of the method. If a method is *overloaded* (i.e. several methods with the same name but different argument types exist), the choice of which method to use is made statically, at compilation time.

Comment: Both of the `equals()` calls are from a `B` object, even though the first call is from inside of class `A` it's still calling from a `B` object isn't it?

What i don't understand is how the two lines act differently...

Comment: The compiler compiles A.toString(). This method calls this.equals(five), where this is of type A. So the compiler searches for a method equals() in A, or in Object. It finds it in A, and thus the method equals(Object) is called. This happens at compilation time. At runtime, this.equals(Object) is called. The runtime looks for such a method in B, and it doesn't exist. **Another** equals() method exists, but with different arguments, so it's irrelevant. So it looks for equals(Object) in A, and it exists. So this method is called.

Comment: What you expect would work if B.equals() overrode A.equals(). For B to override A, it must take Object as argument, not A.